# Access a SQLite database with Adminer 4.8

Tags: php, sqlite, adminer

I want to use Adminer 4.8.1 (latest as I write) with my SQLite 3 database, since, [as written on Adminer website, it supports SQLite](https://www.adminer.org/en/).

However, when I try to connect to my SQLite DB, Adminer says *[Adminer does not support accessing a database without a password](https://www.adminer.org/en/password/)*. Indeed SQLite databases don't have passwords, as Adminer also says it [here](https://www.adminer.org/en/password/): "*Set up the database server to require a password. This is possible with all databases except SQLite and SimpleDB*".

I'm confused. Does Adminer actually support SQLite? What can I do?

Comment: Check the [plugin](https://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/) section. There is a plugin which allows you to connect to a SQLite database w/out password

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee! I guess you're talking about this one https://github.com/FrancoisCapon/LoginToASqlite3DatabaseWithoutCredentialsWithAdminer. Feel free to post this as an answer

Comment: Not sure if that would be an "usefull" answer as it would be a link-only answer which could become invalid overtime